# userEvent.type not updating value of input in test

Tags: reactjs, testing, input

I am testing this component, which is simply changing its state depending on new input into the input field and setting the value of the input element to that state.

```
function Login () {
    //Login Credentials
    const [loginCredentials, setLoginCredentials] = useState({ name: '' })
    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        setLoginCredentials(prev => ({ ...prev, [target.name]: target.value }));
    }

    return (
            <div className="login-container">
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                    <div className="login-label-input">
                        <label htmlFor="name">Account Name
                            <input
                            type="name"
                            id="name"
                            name="name"
                            placeholder="Enter Name"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={loginCredentials.name}
                            aria-label="name"
                            />
                        </label>
                  </div>
             </div>
    )
}
```

and for some reason this test does not show the value of input to be "testUser" in screen.debug() but only "t"....

```
    test("log in with empty name input returns error message",  () => {
    render(<Login />)
    const nameField = screen.getByLabelText(/account name/i);
    userEvent.type(nameField, 'testUser'); 
    screen.debug()
});
```

Shouldn't this work? Why doesn't it? excerpt from screen.debug():

```html
           <label
              for="name"
            >
              Account Name
              <input
                aria-label="name"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter Name"
                type="name"
                value="t"
              />
            </label>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In the current version of `@testing-library/user-event: ^14.2.0` and its corresponding official docs, there is an example where calling `userEvent.type` is awaited:

```
test('type into an input field', async () => {
  render(<input defaultValue="Hello," />)
  const input = screen.getByRole('textbox')

  await userEvent.type(input, ' World!')

  expect(input).toHaveValue('Hello, World!')
})
```

Callback in test() needs to be declared as `async` then, of course.

Link to this in the docs at time of writing: https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility/#type

Nice to know maybe: Also works with uncontrolled components.

Comment: Thank you so much man, I've been trying to get it to work for 20 minutes now 

Answer (score 1):

If you update jest to the latest version it will work. Currently, the latest jest is 26.6.3

This issue was discussed here: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/387

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute "type" is invalid. The value "name" doesn't exist, try "text".

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -2):

first

```
await userEvent.click(input)
await userEvent.clear(input)
```

second

```
await waitFor(()=>{
 await userEvent.type(input, 'World!')
 expect(input).toHaveValue('World!')
})
```

Comment: Your second await won't have any effect because you would need the arrow function to also be async